# Can I send Ether with Mist without syncing it to the current best block?

Tags: transactions, mist, synchronization

Can I safely send Ether after skipping the peer research in Mist?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to, but it might timeout you transaction, as the wallet is checking each for each incoming block if the tx was mined, for the next 50 blocks. If you then sync it will most likely time out the tx in the interface, though the transaction should have been send anyway (and most likely mined).

I would rather wait until synced..