# Why transactions not confirmed when sent by node not fully synced?

Tags: transactions, mist

I'm using Mist wallet, and the local `geth` node is about several thousand blocks behind the head, can I make transactions in this case?

I'm asking because I did send a transaction and it wasn't confirmed for over 12 hours. Is it because I can't send transactions before the node is fully synced up, or because the fee is too low and no miners want to include it?

I used the default value in the fee slider at then, it was about 0.006 ETH, I thought that was enough.

I'm not sure is it even propagated to the network and how can I check this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I send Ether with Mist without syncing it to the current best block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/can-i-send-ether-with-mist-without-syncing-it-to-the-current-best-block)

Comment: Then how to explain my transaction not confirmed in 12 hours?

Comment: Hi there. Did you send your transaction on the main network, or testnet? If you sent it on the main network, then it could be stuck in pending state due to the backlog of transactions. Have you checked for the transaction hash in a chain explorer? (e.g. etherscan.io)

Comment: I think low fee is more likely. Do you have a transaction id to check on etherscan?

Comment: The transaction is: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x82f93877f05fbb79ee5fa5a27f3845babdc579a96bd9c6347993429db71166aa and the fee and other parameters are: http://i.imgur.com/yABz7Ng.png